# Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mentor\checklogin.php on line 20

Tags: php, mysql, post

En mi form tengo los input con los nombres username y password

```
<div class="form-group">
          <form name="" id="loginForm" action="checklogin.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <!----- username -------------->
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="username" />
              <span style="display:none;font-weight:bold; position:absolute;color: red;position: absolute;padding:4px;font-size: 11px;background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.26);z-index: 17;  right: 27px; top: 5px;" id="span_loginid"></span>
              <!---Alredy exists  ! -->
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <!----- password -------------->
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" />
              <span style="display:none;font-weight:bold; position:absolute;color: grey;position: absolute;padding:4px;font-size: 11px;background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.26);z-index: 17;  right: 27px; top: 5px;" id="span_password"></span>
              <!---Alredy exists  ! -->
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="checkbox icheck">
                  <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="loginrem" > Remember Me
                          </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green btn-block btn-flat" onclick="userlogin()">Ingresar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Pero cuando intento obtener los datos de los input con el método post en mi archivo php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php  
include 'conexion.php';

$username = $_POST["username"];

$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM administrador WHERE nombre_admin = '$username'";

$result = $conexion->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     

 }

 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 if (password_verify($password, $row["password"])) { 



    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    $_SESSION['start'] = time();

    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

    echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];

    echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>";

 } else { 

   echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";



   echo "<br><a href='index.php'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";

 }

 mysqli_close($conexion);

 ?>
```

Me genera este error de index "Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mentor\checklogin.php on line 20"

Me pueden explicar que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Intenta darle un `var_dump` a tu variable `$row` para ver que información esta almacenando.

Comment: Podrías indicar si en tu tabla **administrador** tienes una columna que se llama **password**

Comment: no tenia esa columna, gracias, me has salvado